# wkhtmltopdf html to pdf format not consistent

Tags: python, html, pdf, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I'm trying to convert a HTML file to PDF using wkhtmltopdf and pdfkit in python. It converts the file to PDF with no issues, but the formatting is not the same as you can see in the pictures below, with the first one being the HTML file, and the second the converted PDF file.

HTML:
[image: HTML]

PDF:
[image: PDF]

My pdfkit function is as follows:

```
pdfkit.from_file("test.html", "index.pdf", configuration=config, options={"enable-local-file-access": True, "orientation": "landscape", "page-size": "A4"})
```

I've tried increasing the width with "page-width" and increasing "page-size" as well, but no change. Any suggestions as to how I can get the 2 to look the same?

UPDATE:
Gave up on using wkhtmltopdf and pdfkit and used pyhtml2pdf instead and it worked perfectly.

Function is as follows:

```
return converter.convert(url, 'html.pdf', print_options={"paperWidth": 15})
```

Comment: for that you need to set the print media CSS query

Comment: @rahul.m I added the flag "print-media-type": None to the options but no change